# How to return true if two same columns in two different tables have values? SQL

Tags: sql, pivot-table

[image: Table_A][image: Table_B]

Back on here with another question for y'all!

So we have two Pivot tables, Table_A and Table_B. Both tables have the same columns.

I was trying to write a query that'll go through each row and return true ONLY AND ONLY IF the record with the same ID has a value in the 'Value' field. 
So for example, Table_A has 'sdnbfsj' value for record ID3 and Table_B has a value under the 'Value' field for the same record ID.

The query should be able to validate that the same cell in both tables have values and if they do, then return true. If the tables only had three records in total, this would have returned true but notice that record ID 5 has a value in Table_A but record ID 5 is NULL in Table_B. SO the query should return false.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT source_column from 
(
select source_column from Table_A WHERE Value_Inserted=1
EXCEPT
select source_column from Table_B WHERE Value_Inserted=1
)X
WHERE source_column  IN 
(
'Col_1'
,'COl_2'
,'Col_3'
,'Col_4'
)
```

Comment: what's your DB engine???

Comment: Please post what output you expect to see here.

Comment: Also, please put in your data as plain text and not images

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by first Joining the two tables on `id` and then counting based on your condition. Then... return "true" or "false"

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t1.value IS NOT NULL AND t2.value IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = Count(*) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END as test
FROM table_a as t1
    INNER JOIN table_b as t2 ON
        t1.id = t2.id
```

Syntax may differ depending on what RDBMS you use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select min(case when a.value is not null and a.value is null then 0
                when a.value is null a and a.value is not null then 0
                else 1
           end) as flag
from a join
     b
     on a.class = b.class and a.source_col = b.source_col;
```

This treats 1 as true and 0 as false.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the *DBMS* that you're using ;

For **Oracle** use `nvl2` function :

```
select nvl2(a.value, 1, 0) * nvl2(b.value, 1, 0)
  from Table_A a
 inner join Table_B b
    on (a.ID = b.ID);
```

For **MSSQL** `convert` or `cast` functions might be used  :

```
select   convert(int, ( case when IsNull(a.value,'0') = '0' then '0' 
              else '1' 
         end ))
         *
         convert(int, ( case when IsNull(b.value,'0') = '0' then '0' 
              else '1' 
         end )) as result
  from Table_A a
 inner join Table_B b
    on (a.ID = b.ID);
```

For **MySQL** use `IfNull` function :

```
select   ( case when IfNull(a.value,'0') = '0' then '0' 
              else '1' 
         end )
         *
         ( case when IfNull(b.value,'0') = '0' then '0' 
              else '1' 
         end ) as result
  from Table_A a
 inner join Table_B b
    on (a.ID = b.ID);
```

For **PostGreSQL** use `coalesce` function :

```
select   cast( ( case when coalesce(a.value,'0') = '0' then '0' 
              else '1' 
         end ) as int )
         *
         cast( ( case when coalesce(b.value,'0') = '0' then '0' 
              else '1' 
         end ) as int ) as result
  from Table_A a
 inner join Table_B b
    on (a.ID = b.ID);
```

All of them give the following results

```
result
  0
  0
  1
  0
  0
```